# No puedo sobrecargar función miembro de una plantilla

Tags: c++, template

Tengo una clase que encapsula la llamada a una función miembro de una clase. La gracia de este encapsulamiento es que puedo inyectar operaciones en tiempo de ejecución que se ejecutarán antes o después de la propia llamada a la función. Muy útil para, por ejemplo, asociar un log a ciertas llamadas sin tener que modificar la clase original.

Un ejemplo bastante simplificado de la clase podría ser este:

```
template<class Type, class ReturnType, class ... Args>
class FunctionWrapper
{
public:

  using FuncType = ReturnType (Type::*)(Args ...);

  FunctionWrapper(FuncType function)
    : m_function{function}
  { }

  ReturnType operator()(Type* type, Args ... args)
  {
    PreOperations();

    ReturnType toReturn = (type->*m_function)(args...);

    PostOperations();

    return toReturn;
  }

private:

  FuncType m_function;

  void PreOperations()
  { /* ... */ }

  void PostOperations()
  { /* ... */ }
};
```

La clase en líneas generales cumple con su cometido:

```
struct POO
{
  int func1(int a)
  { return a*2; }

  void func2(int a)
  { std::cout << a; }
};

int main()
{
  FunctionWrapper<POO,int,int> wrapper1(&POO::func1);

  POO poo;
  std::cout << wrapper1(&poo,5);
}
```

Sin embargo no es perfecta y falla cuando la función a encapsular tiene como tipo de retorno `void`. Así la siguientes líneas:

```
FunctionWrapper<POO,void,int> wrapper2(&POO::func2);
wrapper2(&poo,5);
```

Generan un error en tiempo de compilación:

```
error: variable has incomplete type 'void'
    ReturnType toReturn = (type->*m_function)(args...);
               ^
```

El problema está en que como la plantilla está definida a nivel de clase no puedo deshabilitar la función usando SFINAE:

```
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<ReturnType,void>::value,void>::type
operator()(Type* type, Args ... args)
{
  PreOperations();

  (type->*m_function)(args...);

  PostOperations();
}

typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<ReturnType,void>::value,ReturnType>::type
operator()(Type* type, Args ... args)
{
  PreOperations();

  ReturnType toReturn = (type->*m_function)(args...);

  PostOperations();

  return toReturn;
}
```

El compilador ya se encarga de hacerme saber que no compra la solución:

```
error: failed requirement 'std::is_same<int, void>::value'; 'enable_if' cannot be used to disable this declaration
  typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<ReturnType,void>::value,void>::type
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

¿De qué forma se puede solucionar este problema?

Comment: @fedorqui ¿mejor así?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para estos casos, la expresión constante condicional es la solución:

```
ReturnType operator()(Type* type, Args ... args)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same<ReturnType,void>::value)
    {
        PreOperations();

        (type->*m_function)(args...);

        PostOperations();
    }
    else
    {
        PreOperations();

        ReturnType toReturn = (type->*m_function)(args...);

        PostOperations();

        return toReturn;
    }
}
```

Dependiendo del resultado de la expresión constante `std::is_same` se compilará una rama de la condición constante o la otra, esquivando el problema de que la plantilla esté definida a nivel de clase.

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Wandbox 三へ( へ՞ਊ ՞)へ ﾊｯﾊｯ](https://wandbox.org/permlink/FgWKYd7QSUpn7Jnm)</kbd>.

En caso de no disponer de un compilador que ofrezca la expresión constante condicional se puede optar por una solución menos clara e intuitiva:

```
ReturnType operator()(Type* type, Args ... args)
{
    PreOperations();
    return PostOperations(), (type->*m_function)(args...);
}
```

Esta aproximación funciona porque se puede devolver `void` en una función cuyo tipo de retorno es `void`, el problema es que `PostOperations` es llamada antes del funtor y asumo que el objetivo es que sea llamada después, para ello deberíamos crear una clase auxiliar que llamase `PreOperations` al construirse y `PostOperations` al destruirse:

```
template<class Type, class ReturnType, class ... Args>
class FunctionWrapper
{
    // ...

private:

    friend struct ingnorame;
    template <typename T>
    struct ingnorame
    {
        ingnorame(T &t) : host{t} { host.PreOperations(); }
        ~ingnorame() { host.PostOperations(); }
        T &host;
    };
    // ...
};
```

Y darle uso en la llamada al operador paréntesis:

```
ReturnType operator()(Type* type, Args ... args)
{
    ingnorame<decltype(*this)> temp{*this};
    return (type->*m_function)(args...);
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Wandbox 三へ( へ՞ਊ ՞)へ ﾊｯﾊｯ](https://wandbox.org/permlink/9RRQ5KiQanmhvIOw)</kbd>.